# Server TCP stuck on read()

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to get a server to receive messages from a client in TCP.
The problem is, I only receive the messages on the server side once I close the socket on the client side.

Here is the read function on the server side:

```
char *read_socket(int fd){
      int bytesRcvd, aux;

      char *buffer=(char*)malloc(BUFFSIZE*sizeof(char));

      bytesRcvd=read(fd, buffer , BUFFSIZE);
      aux=bytesRcvd;

      while(bytesRcvd>0){
        if((bytesRcvd = read(fd, &buffer[aux], BUFFSIZE))<0){
          printf("read() failed!: %s\n", strerror(errno));
          exit(1);
        }

        aux+=bytesRcvd;

      }
    return &buffer[0];
}
```

I know (by printfs) that it gets stuck on the line:

```
bytesRcvd = read(fd, &buffer[aux], BUFFSIZE)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: well, despite the fact that your little example is full of bug, read default behavior is to block, he will only return 0 if the connection shutdown (you don't handle 0 in your example). You can use select(), poll(), epoll(), etc. Or put the socket in non blocking mode.

Comment: TCP applications usually use some kind of message delimiters. Telnet, SMTP, POP, IMAP all use "\r\n" line termination. HTTP/1.1 uses "\r\n\r\n" to show the end of the header block and then manages the size of the HTTP Body with Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding chunked, or it just closes the connection.

Comment: Note:evenauzcanbe-1:  `if((bytesRcvd = read(fd, &buffer[aux], BUFFSIZE))<0){` And read()returning -1 is not necessarily an error: errno could be EINTR/EAGAIN. And `(bytesRcvd = read(fd, &buffer[aux], BUFFSIZE)` could overflow the buffer if more than BUFFSIZE-aux bytes are read by the second read().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is reading the data in the line:

```
bytesRcvd = read(fd, &buffer[aux], BUFFSIZE)
```

Your while loop receives the data that the client sends. If the client doesn't have data to send read will **block** until the connection is closed where read will `return 0` and you will exit from while loop.

This is the reason that you think that the data are send in the end (when connection is closed). This is not right, if you print the data you read in the while loop you will see them immediately and not all of them in the end.

Though you can't return the data before the connection is closed due to `read()` **blocking**.

For one client your program may seems ok if you don't have the problem of getting data at the end (as I said you could just print them inside while loop) but imagine have two or more clients then you would firstly close connection with first client to go on and read data from second and so on.

One solution(to both problems) is to use `select()` system call, this will go on to read only if there are data.( Though `select()` is not safe when using `fork()`- doesn't guarantee that a parent of child process will not block in read() ).

Comment: Well, the real reason is not that read() is blocking, the program could very well find the part of the message it wants (if the client sends a hint about where the message begins or ends). The `while(bytesRcvd>0)` is the reason the function does not return until the client closes the connection - read() returns 0 when the connection is closed, and the code does not exit the loop until that happens.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean and what I'm describing... The blocking of read does not help to exit the while loop since it blocks, I already wrote that he could print the messages inside loop!!! Maybe I'm not terribly clear but I don't think I writing something wrong...Anyway thanks for comment since it describes it a bit further!!